# bash arguments list too long on linux but not on mac

Tags: linux, bash

Here is the shell script that I run:

```
for file in “$d/resources/“*; do
        resourceName=$(basename $file)
        echo “Inserting resouce: $resourceName...”
        resource=`cat $file`
        # Generate id with md5
        resourceId=$((resourceId+1))
        # Insert into resources table
        cqlsh -e “INSERT INTO $TENANT_NAME.resources (id, target,lastUpdateDate,lastUpdateUser,algorithmName,resourceName,resourceContent) VALUES ( $resourceId, ‘template’, toTimestamp(now()), null, ‘$algorithmName’, ‘$resourceName’, \$\$$resource\$\$);” $STORAGE_HOST_ADDRESS $STORAGE_HOST_PORT
    done
```

On mac it works fine, but on linux it throws the error bash arguments list too long becaue of $resource. Can someone please tell how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Look at your environment variable set; you could just use `env` to get the list. On both Linux and MacOS, everything you `export` counts against your maximum command-line argument list length (which is why you should just assign variables without the `export` keyword unless you have a very specific reason to store them in the environment block rather than the shell's dynamically-allocated heap).

Comment: BTW, the code pasted here has "smart quotes". Bash doesn't honor those; you need to use `"..."` and `'...'`, not `“...”`/`‘...’`.

Comment: ...I'd also generally suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the other (mostly quoting-related) bugs it finds. But the immediate cause of your bug is going to be in the contents of your environment, unrelated to the script you gave itself.

Comment: (That said, how large are your resource files? If they're over 100-200KB or so, then yes, you may have a real problem independent of variable sizes... though at that point I'd expect it to be a problem on the Mac too; different kernels, so the sizes aren't identical, but there's an OS-defined limit either way).

Comment: If it's between 128 and 256k, then it'll fail on Linux by not on macOS. If it's over, it'll fail on both.

Comment: Surely `cqlsh` provides a mechanism for reading from a stream rather than from its arguments.  Use that.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy. Regarding your first comment, I didn't use `export` assgin variables. But yes, the fize size can be 170kb.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has a limit of 128k per argument. macOS has a limit of 256k for arguments+environment.

Write the query to a file instead, and have `cqlsh` execute that instead of an environment:

```
cqlsh -f myqueryfile host port
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but the resource content that I was inserting is too large and this makes cqlsh spent at least 20 mins to read it. Is there any way that I can fix this slow insert problem?

Comment: Are you saying that the `-e` is significantly faster than `-f`, even when both work correctly (and `-e` doesn't fail immediately due to the error you asked about)?

Comment: When file size is small, both -e and -f work. When file size is large, -e doesn't work, -f works but is slow.

Comment: `cqlsh` being slow for certain queries is an entirely separate issue from getting "arguments list too long" when running a shell command...